# How to export response into a file or validate the tag value with the help of Karate Framework

Tags: selenium, automation, web-api-testing, karate

I'm using the following feature file and it generates the response. How can we store the response into an XML file instead of showing the console?

**Feature File:**

```
Feature: Test soap end point

    Background:
    * url 'sample url'

    Scenario: SmokeTest
       Given request read('getMbrWksMembershipDetails.xml')
       When soap action 'test url' 
       Then status 200
       And print response
```

EDITED: The response I'm getting like this.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns1:getMbrWksMembershipDetailsResponse xmlns:ns1="xxxxxxxxxx">
         <ns4:WksMembershipSummaryResponse xmlns:ns2="xxxxxxxx" xmlns:ns3="xxxxxxxxxx" xmlns:ns4="xxxxxxxxxx">
            <ns2:customerSummary>
               <ns2:address>
                  <ns2:city>SOUTH CHESTERFIELD</ns2:city>
                  <ns2:country>USA</ns2:country>
                  <ns2:isoCountryCode>US</ns2:isoCountryCode>
                  <ns2:line1>9998, N. MICHIGAN ROAD.</ns2:line1>
                  <ns2:postalCode>23834</ns2:postalCode>
                  <ns2:state>VA</ns2:state>
               </ns2:address>
               <ns2:allowPasswordChange>true</ns2:allowPasswordChange>
               <ns2:arpMember>false</ns2:arpMember>
               <ns2:brandCode>ABC</ns2:brandCode>
               <ns2:brandId>1</ns2:brandId>
               <ns2:companyCode>ABC</ns2:companyCode>
               <ns2:eliteMemberRewardStatus>false</ns2:eliteMemberRewardStatus>.....
```

**Question:**
How can I validate the tag values from this response?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi, I have updated the questions, please give your suggestion for my post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a question - why do you want to do this ? Karate is a testing framework, and besides being able to run assertions on responses, you can easily re-use responses (or some data from a response) in the next request. There is no need to ever save anything to a file.

And if you follow the instructions in the Karate documentation on [logging](https://github.com/intuit/karate#logging) you will also see responses logged to the file `target/karate.log`.

When you use the JUnit runner, you will see all responses in an [HTML report](https://github.com/intuit/karate#junit-html-report).

Same case with the [parallel runner](https://github.com/intuit/karate#test-reports).

Anyway, even after all this if you really really want to save responses to a file, use [Java interop](https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java) and write your own utility to save to a file, it will be a just a few lines of code. It is not built-in to Karate because of the above reasons.

EDIT: well, after all the typing above, turns out you just want to know how to validate (assert / match) the response ? Great, that is the whole selling point of Karate.

I assume you have read the [Karate documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate). Also refer this example: [`soap.xml`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/soap/soap.feature) and this one for more ideas: [`xml.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/xml/xml.feature)

Anyway here are some hints based on your XML sample to get you started. You can paste the below into a `Scenario:` and run this without needing to make HTTP requests and that way test and get comfortable with `match`:

```
* def response = 
"""
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns1:getMbrWksMembershipDetailsResponse xmlns:ns1="xxxxxxxxxx">
         <ns4:WksMembershipSummaryResponse xmlns:ns2="xxxxxxxx" xmlns:ns3="xxxxxxxxxx" xmlns:ns4="xxxxxxxxxx">
            <ns2:customerSummary>
               <ns2:address>
                  <ns2:city>SOUTH CHESTERFIELD</ns2:city>
                  <ns2:country>USA</ns2:country>
                  <ns2:isoCountryCode>US</ns2:isoCountryCode>
                  <ns2:line1>9998, N. MICHIGAN ROAD.</ns2:line1>
                  <ns2:postalCode>23834</ns2:postalCode>
                  <ns2:state>VA</ns2:state>
               </ns2:address>
            </ns2:customerSummary>
        </ns4:WksMembershipSummaryResponse>
    </ns1:getMbrWksMembershipDetailsResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
"""
* match //address/city == 'SOUTH CHESTERFIELD'

* match //customerSummary/address == 
    """
    <ns2:address>
       <ns2:city>SOUTH CHESTERFIELD</ns2:city>
       <ns2:country>USA</ns2:country>
       <ns2:isoCountryCode>US</ns2:isoCountryCode>
       <ns2:line1>9998, N. MICHIGAN ROAD.</ns2:line1>
       <ns2:postalCode>23834</ns2:postalCode>
       <ns2:state>VA</ns2:state>
    </ns2:address>
    """
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. I have to validate some of the tag values present in the SOAP response. I tried with xpath expressions to get the value of the tag as mentioned in the documentation. But I'm failed to get the result. EDITED THE POST

Comment: @Karunagara you should really read the documentation. anyway, edited the post.